Dropdown UI Black Screen Issue on Android in Phaser Game
I’m encountering an issue with a custom dropdown in my Phaser 3 game. The dropdown works perfectly on iOS and web, but on Android (APK), the screen turns black when I attempt to display the dropdown list. The dropdown is created using the DOM and dynamically populated with options. Here’s how I’m adding the dropdown:
// Create a dropdown using HTML
const dropdown = document.createElement('select');
dropdown.style.position = 'absolute';
dropdown.style.zIndex = '1000';

const option1 = document.createElement('option');
option1.value = '1';
option1.text = 'Option 1';
dropdown.appendChild(option1);

const option2 = document.createElement('option');
option2.value = '2';
option2.text = 'Option 2';
dropdown.appendChild(option2);

document.body.appendChild(dropdown);
dropdown.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  const selectedValue = (event.target as HTMLSelectElement).value;
  console.log('Selected Value:', selectedValue);
  if (selectedValue === '1') {
    console.log('Option 1 selected');
  } else if (selectedValue === '2') {
    console.log('Option 2 selected');
  }

my gameconfig looks like below
export class RobotGame extends Phaser.Game {
constructor() {
    super({
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        scale: {
            width: Dimensions.designResolution.width,
            height: Dimensions.designResolution.height,
            mode: Phaser.Scale.NONE,
        },
        backgroundColor: "#000000",
        banner: false,
        zoom: 1,
        autoMobilePipeline: true,
        plugins: {
            global: [

            ],
            scene: [
                {
                    key: "rexGestures",
                    plugin: gestures,
                    mapping: "rexGestures",
                },
            ],
        },
        loader: {
            crossOrigin: "anonymous",
            baseURL: CDN_PATH,
        },
        parent: "DOMElementParent",
        dom: {
            createContainer: true,
        },
        render: {
            transparent: true,
            powerPreference: "high-performance",
            autoMobilePipeline: true,
        },
    });

    this.canvas.className = "game_canvas";

    SafeArea.getSafeAreaInsets().then((safeArea) => {
        this.bootGame(safeArea);
    });
}

private bootGame(safeArea: SafeAreaInsets): void {
    const ppi = window.devicePixelRatio;
    Dimensions.safeAreaInsets = {
        top: safeArea.insets.top * ppi,
        right: safeArea.insets.right * ppi,
        bottom: safeArea.insets.bottom * ppi,
        left: safeArea.insets.left * ppi,
    };

    this.scene.add("Boot", new Boot());
    this.scene.start("Boot");
}


using Phaser: 3
Capacitor : 6
@capacitor/android": “^6.0.0”

screenShot of dropdown looks like below

I suspect it might be related to DOM element rendering on Android. Any ideas or suggestions on debugging or fixing this?

Has it to do with the font-color or so? this doesn't seem to be a phaser error, or does the Error only appear it the phaser game is loaded? Asked differnetly does the html/dorpdown code work without the phaser game?

Yes, the HTML dropdown works fine on its own. However, when added to the Phaser canvas, it appears black when the dropdown is opened. This issue occurs only on Android, whereas it works fine on the web. Additionally, no specific styles, font colors, or background colors have been applied to the dropdown.

Maybe no Styles were set to the dropdown perse, but if styles were added, in generell to the HTML, or the parent Tag, these might cascade down, or simply from the Browser/Phones/Os current Theme, styles are passed on. These all effect the DOM. Are you using a CSS reset file/directive?

If it is no "styling"-issue, can you share some more relevant code. MRE go a long way.

Thank you for looking to it, but after a thorough observation, I found that the issue was not with Phaser or the HTML code but with the colour of the WebView on the Android system. Specifically, I had to go through the styles.xml file under res/values and change <item name="android:background">@android:color/black</item> to a more suitable colour to ensure the font and background matched.

Thank you for sharing your result/solution. :)

Well some parts are missing, but let me assume, since the code-snippets leave alot of room for speculation, and I could reproduce this issue with the provide code (or maybe I'm missing something):

The issue has to do something with styling of the html elements, and the browser / phone default theme (Dark-Theme or so). Since the selection is visible (the lila dot, but the text not)
The used Dropdown is only on the html page, not connected with the Phaser game. (If this was intended, you would have to use this.add.dom link to documentation). This disconnect/overlay, might cause issues.

Sidenote phaser html-elements (canvas/domContainer) should not be css-styled, since this can cause display issues.

Tip:
If you are willing to use phaser - plugins you could check this plugin(s), the offer UI-Controlls, "inside of phaser", and this would look the same on each platform (more or less, atleast more consitent than HTML-controls)

